# How to check if any string is missing in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have following dataframe in pandas

```
 Date           half_hourly_bucket       Value
 2018-01-01     00:00:01 - 00:30:00      123
 2018-01-01     00:30:01 - 01:00:00      12
 2018-01-01     01:00:01 - 01:30:00      122
 2018-01-01     02:00:01 - 02:30:00      111
 2018-01-01     03:00:01 - 03:30:00      122
 2018-01-01     04:00:01 - 04:30:00      111
```

My desired dataframe would be

```
 Date           half_hourly_bucket       Value
 2018-01-01     00:00:01 - 00:30:00      123
 2018-01-01     00:30:01 - 01:00:00      12
 2018-01-01     01:00:01 - 01:30:00      122
 2018-01-01     01:30:01 - 02:00:00      0
 2018-01-01     02:00:01 - 02:30:00      122
 2018-01-01     02:30:01 - 03:00:00      0
 2018-01-01     03:00:01 - 03:30:00      111
 2018-01-01     03:30:01 - 04:00:00      0
 2018-01-01     04:00:01 - 04:30:00      111
 2018-01-01     04:30:01 - 05:00:00      0
 2018-01-01     05:00:01 - 05:30:00      0
 2018-01-01     05:30:01 - 06:00:00      0
 2018-01-01     06:00:01 - 06:30:00      0
 2018-01-01     06:30:01 - 07:00:00      0
 2018-01-01     07:00:01 - 07:30:00      0
 2018-01-01     07:30:01 - 08:00:00      0
 2018-01-01     08:00:01 - 08:30:00      0
 2018-01-01     09:00:01 - 09:30:00      0
 2018-01-01     10:00:01 - 10:30:00      0
 2018-01-01     10:30:01 - 11:00:00      0
 2018-01-01     11:00:01 - 11:30:00      0
 2018-01-01     11:30:01 - 12:00:00      0
 2018-01-01     12:00:01 - 12:30:00      0
 2018-01-01     12:30:01 - 13:00:00      0
 2018-01-01     13:00:01 - 13:30:00      0
 2018-01-01     13:30:01 - 14:00:00      0
 2018-01-01     14:00:01 - 14:30:00      0
 2018-01-01     14:30:01 - 15:00:00      0
 2018-01-01     15:00:01 - 15:30:00      0
 2018-01-01     15:30:01 - 16:00:00      0
 2018-01-01     16:00:01 - 16:30:00      0
 2018-01-01     16:30:01 - 17:00:00      0
 2018-01-01     17:00:01 - 17:30:00      0
 2018-01-01     18:00:01 - 18:30:00      0
 2018-01-01     18:30:01 - 19:00:00      0
 2018-01-01     19:00:01 - 19:30:00      0
 2018-01-01     19:30:01 - 20:00:00      0
 2018-01-01     20:00:01 - 20:30:00      0
 2018-01-01     20:30:01 - 21:00:00      0
 2018-01-01     21:00:01 - 21:30:00      0
 2018-01-01     21:30:01 - 22:00:00      0
 2018-01-01     22:00:01 - 22:30:00      0
 2018-01-01     22:30:01 - 23:00:00      0
 2018-01-01     23:00:01 - 23:30:00      0
 2018-01-01     23:30:01 - 00:00:00      0
```

What I want to check on `Date` column is if in any half hourly bucket (48 buckets in total per day) there is missing data and if it is missing then that bucket has to be added in order and will have value as 0.

How can I do it in pandas?

Answer (score 4):

Solution break `half_hourly_bucket` to 2 new columns, process it and join back:

```
#create DatetimeIndex
df = df.set_index('Date')

#split to new columns
df[['one','two']] = df['half_hourly_bucket'].str.split(' - ', expand=True)

#add first column to DatetimeIndex
df.index += pd.to_timedelta(df['one'])

#add mising values to DatetimeIndex
one_sec = pd.Timedelta(1, unit='s')
one_day = pd.Timedelta(1, unit='d')
df = df.reindex(pd.date_range(df.index.min().floor('D') + one_sec, 
                              df.index.max().floor('D') + one_day - one_sec, freq='30T'))

#recreate column two
df['two'] = df.index + pd.Timedelta(30*60 - 1, unit='s')
#join together
df['half_hourly_bucket'] = (df.index.strftime('%H:%M:%S') + ' - ' +
                            df['two'].dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S'))

#replace missing values
df['Value'] = df['Value'].fillna(0)

df = df.rename_axis('Date').reset_index()

#filter only necessary columns
df = df[['Date','half_hourly_bucket','Value']]
```

---

```
print (df)

                  Date   half_hourly_bucket  Value
0  2018-01-01 00:00:01  00:00:01 - 00:30:00  123.0
1  2018-01-01 00:30:01  00:30:01 - 01:00:00   12.0
2  2018-01-01 01:00:01  01:00:01 - 01:30:00  122.0
3  2018-01-01 01:30:01  01:30:01 - 02:00:00    0.0
4  2018-01-01 02:00:01  02:00:01 - 02:30:00  111.0
5  2018-01-01 02:30:01  02:30:01 - 03:00:00    0.0
6  2018-01-01 03:00:01  03:00:01 - 03:30:00  122.0
7  2018-01-01 03:30:01  03:30:01 - 04:00:00    0.0
8  2018-01-01 04:00:01  04:00:01 - 04:30:00  111.0
9  2018-01-01 04:30:01  04:30:01 - 05:00:00    0.0
10 2018-01-01 05:00:01  05:00:01 - 05:30:00    0.0
11 2018-01-01 05:30:01  05:30:01 - 06:00:00    0.0
12 2018-01-01 06:00:01  06:00:01 - 06:30:00    0.0
13 2018-01-01 06:30:01  06:30:01 - 07:00:00    0.0
14 2018-01-01 07:00:01  07:00:01 - 07:30:00    0.0
15 2018-01-01 07:30:01  07:30:01 - 08:00:00    0.0
16 2018-01-01 08:00:01  08:00:01 - 08:30:00    0.0
17 2018-01-01 08:30:01  08:30:01 - 09:00:00    0.0
18 2018-01-01 09:00:01  09:00:01 - 09:30:00    0.0
19 2018-01-01 09:30:01  09:30:01 - 10:00:00    0.0
20 2018-01-01 10:00:01  10:00:01 - 10:30:00    0.0
21 2018-01-01 10:30:01  10:30:01 - 11:00:00    0.0
22 2018-01-01 11:00:01  11:00:01 - 11:30:00    0.0
23 2018-01-01 11:30:01  11:30:01 - 12:00:00    0.0
24 2018-01-01 12:00:01  12:00:01 - 12:30:00    0.0
25 2018-01-01 12:30:01  12:30:01 - 13:00:00    0.0
26 2018-01-01 13:00:01  13:00:01 - 13:30:00    0.0
27 2018-01-01 13:30:01  13:30:01 - 14:00:00    0.0
28 2018-01-01 14:00:01  14:00:01 - 14:30:00    0.0
29 2018-01-01 14:30:01  14:30:01 - 15:00:00    0.0
30 2018-01-01 15:00:01  15:00:01 - 15:30:00    0.0
31 2018-01-01 15:30:01  15:30:01 - 16:00:00    0.0
32 2018-01-01 16:00:01  16:00:01 - 16:30:00    0.0
33 2018-01-01 16:30:01  16:30:01 - 17:00:00    0.0
34 2018-01-01 17:00:01  17:00:01 - 17:30:00    0.0
35 2018-01-01 17:30:01  17:30:01 - 18:00:00    0.0
36 2018-01-01 18:00:01  18:00:01 - 18:30:00    0.0
37 2018-01-01 18:30:01  18:30:01 - 19:00:00    0.0
38 2018-01-01 19:00:01  19:00:01 - 19:30:00    0.0
39 2018-01-01 19:30:01  19:30:01 - 20:00:00    0.0
40 2018-01-01 20:00:01  20:00:01 - 20:30:00    0.0
41 2018-01-01 20:30:01  20:30:01 - 21:00:00    0.0
42 2018-01-01 21:00:01  21:00:01 - 21:30:00    0.0
43 2018-01-01 21:30:01  21:30:01 - 22:00:00    0.0
44 2018-01-01 22:00:01  22:00:01 - 22:30:00    0.0
45 2018-01-01 22:30:01  22:30:01 - 23:00:00    0.0
46 2018-01-01 23:00:01  23:00:01 - 23:30:00    0.0
47 2018-01-01 23:30:01  23:30:01 - 00:00:00    0.0
```

Comment: I am getting this error while creating new datetime index `ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis`

Comment: I ran your code,but it does not give me desired output. For a specific date there will be `48` half an hourly buckets. If there are only 45 buckets present for that day then missing 3 buckets should be added. I have edited my question